# How could I display all the text of a column in a list?

Tags: json, list, sharepoint

I am using share point online and there is a news list. The problem of this list is that it shows only few lines of text in the Body column. If I want it to show all the text I must click on “Show all” and then it shows all. I want the Body column to show all the text as default, but I don’t know how to do it since the list is made by someone I don’t know.

I appreciate for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean modern news web part or multiple lines of text in the list?

For modern news web part, there is no option to achieve this.

For multiple lines of text in the list, you could use following JSON formatting.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "white-space": "normal",
    "padding": "11px 0",
    "display": "block"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah for my previous post about showing the div code etc, that was because, I had selected the text type on rich text with formatting...
If you use the json script without formatting it works fine.